# Prevent cross-forest KMS client registration

Tags: active-directory, kms

We have one domain, with KMS server activating windows and MS Office corrctly. Recently we have set up a new domain in a new forest and added as trusted forest(we're setting this domain up for another business unit which is going to be spun off).

The first couple of clients we've built on the domain have obtained activation from our main domain KMS server. I didn't think this was supposed to happen? Is there a way to diagnose how this is happening, or to prevent it on a domain-wide basis? I'd want them to activate normally with MS for now, and eventually via a new KMS or ADBA server once they have their own licence agreement.

Comment: What is the DNS record for the KMS in the new forest?

Comment: There isn't one. Presumably the DNS request is being forwarded to the old forest/domain and therefore that one is being used?

Comment: Presumably? How are you validating the DNS record? KMS clients find the KMS server with either a DNS request, or they have been configured to use a specific KMS server by using the `-skms:` switch.